# Section of pull back of co-tangent bundle of a Fano manifold under evaluation map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be smooth Fano variety of dimension $n$ of Picard number one. Assume $TX$ is not nef, where $TX$ denotes the tangent bundle of $X$.
Let $K$ be a component of the Hilbert scheme of rational curves in $X$. Let $x$ be a general point in $X$. Let $K_x$ be the subvariety of $K$ consisting curves passing through $x$. Consider the evaluation map $\phi: \mathbb{P}^1 \times K_x \to X$. Further assume that for any $l \in K_x, T^*X\vert_l$ has a non zero section.

Question: Does $\phi^*T^*X$ have a non-zero section ?